# Vray LICENSE_CHECKOUT_BUCKET_SIZE In AWS Servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deadlines

We start a rendering process on AWS. We bought maya and vray licenses from AWS thinkbox markt, but when we use it, it gives a vray error and this error is related to ports.
Error Message: **Could not start a Port Forwarder on the local machine for port 30306. This is likely due to a port conflict. Please ensure that you are not running a License Forwarder or another Worker on this machine and that no other process are attempting to bind to this port.**
And we are sure that nothing is running on that port.

Deadline Version:10.3.1.3

what should we do

We connect to the Worker Session Manager Command line, write this code and kill that port, but it still doesn't work.

`ps -ef | grep 30306`

Comment: That's not showing processes that have that port open.  Something like `sudo lsof -i -P | grep :30306` would show you that.